# Extend get_european_union_countries() function in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm using a filter that targets the EU countries, which works well. However - I would like to included UK which isn't part of the EU anymore as well as US.

Is there a way to extend get_european_union_countries() function in WooCommerce? So I get a specific country (UK, US) from WC_Countries, so I can add it to my `true` statement in my existing code?

```php
add_filter( 'wc_aelia_tdbc_keep_prices_fixed', function($keep_prices_fixed): bool {        
    $countries = new WC_Countries();
    $eu_countries = $countries->get_european_union_countries();

    if ( WC()->customer ) {
       if ( in_array( WC()->customer->get_billing_country(), $eu_countries ) ) {
            $keep_prices_fixed = true;
        } else {
            $keep_prices_fixed = false;
        }
    }

    return $keep_prices_fixed;
});
```

Comment: All `get_european_union_countries` does, is return an array with the two-uppercase-letters country codes. So unless you assume the country codes for US and UK to change at some point in the foreseeable future, you might as well just add those two to the array yourself ...

Comment: @CBroe Yes, this is basically my question - how to add it to the array

Comment: `$eu_countries[] = 'UK';` ...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides using your existing code you can use the `woocommerce_european_union_countries` filter hook

So you get:

```
function filter_woocommerce_european_union_countries( $countries, $type ) { 
    // Add to the array
    array_push( $countries, 'UK', 'US' );
    
    return $countries;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_european_union_countries', 'filter_woocommerce_european_union_countries', 10, 2 );
```